# B2G os XmlHttpRequest not sending Cookie header after redirect response header

Tags: cookies, firefox-os

I am working on B2G OS. I am trying to hit one API using XHR which is redirecting me to another API with `Set-Cookie` response header. In the next API request that cookie which I got in the first header response which is missing in request header.

Answer (score 0):

Use option 'redirect' : 'follow' while making xhr request, also add systenxhr permission in manifest if this is cross origin request.

Comment: actually this issue was in OS side, but they have done some changes after that it start working automatically